# FizzBuzz for Javascript: How console.log knows when to print one variable or another?

Tags: javascript, logic, fizzbuzz

I'm looking at this code:

```
for (let n = 1; n <=100; n++) {
  let output = "";
  if (n % 3 == 0) output += "Fizz";
  if (n % 5 == 0) output += "Buzz";
console.log(output || n);
}
```

How the console decides when to print the numbers or the words?

Comment: the `||` is telling it to print words, but if it is `falsey` print the number

Comment: console.log doesn't "know" anything, it outputs what you tell it to output - your question really is "what is the || operator" - and for that, there is documentation and about 1000 questions on SO for that :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`""` is a falsy value, so when performing `"" || 1`, it will be read as `false || 1`, which will print `1`.

You can read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

The logical OR operator works because in Javascript, it returns the first expression if if *truthy*, otherwise it returns the second expression.

Read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical